# For what values of $g$, $h$ and $k$ will this system have a solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Consider the following system of equations:

$x − 4y + 7z = g$

$3x − 9y − 5z = h$

$−2x + 5y + 12z = k$

For what values of $g$, $h$ and $k$ will this system have a solution?

How do I solve this? I've never come across a matrix with variables in the solution side. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite your equation in the following form :

$\pmatrix{1 & -4 & 7 \\ 3 & -9 & -5 \\ -2 & 5 & 12} \times \pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z} = \pmatrix{g \\ h \\ k}$

An equation of this form has a solution if and only if $\pmatrix{g \\ h \\ k}$ is in the image of the matrix $A$ (with $A = \pmatrix{1 & -4 & 7 \\ 3 & -9 & -5 \\ -2 & 5 & 12}$). In particular, I would suggest doing gaussian elimination on $(A|\pmatrix{g \\ h \\ k})$ in order to get the necessary conditions on $\pmatrix{g \\ h \\ k}$ for the equation to have a solution.

Comment: When I try to do gaussian elimination, I get crazy fractions that I don't think I can simplify to get a solid answer

Comment: When doing gaussian elimination, you can, sometimes, decide not to divide lines so that the first coefficients become $1$. What I got by doing it is that $h + k - g = 0$ at the end of it.

Comment: Okay I got to h + k - g = 0 by subtracting the second equation from the first equation. How do I find the exact values of g, h, and k now?

Comment: There are no "exact" values of $g,h$ and $k$. The problem was "Given $g,h,k$, will the equation have solution?" You have proven that as long as $h+k=g$ the system has solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the second equation from the first equation, notice that the LHS is the LHS of the third equation so we require that $\color{blue}{g-h=k}$ for a solutions to exist.

Comment: What would I have to do after that to figure out the exact values of g, h, and k?

Comment: You will be able to find a $1$ dimensional family of solutions for $(x,y,z)$ in terms of $g$ and $h$. No solutions will exist if we do not have $g-h=k$.